# CanCan defining abilities with has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have tried for about 2 hours to get this done and I simply can't. None of the found answers to my problem seem to work.

I have a has_many :through associations as such:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :dialogs
  has_many :companies, :through => :dialogs

class Dialog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request
  belongs_to :company
```

In my ability.rb file I am trying to make a company only be able to see its requests (ie to see if the current_user id is in the dialog of the specific request).

I have tried many approaches, but didn't get anywhere. I have to be close somehow, but can't figure it out:

```
can [:show, :destroy], Request, :dialogs => {:company_id => user.rolable.id}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Doesn't your use have a rolable_id method? And shouldn't it be rollable rather than rolable?

Comment: Yes, it does have a rolable_id. It is a polymorphic association with 2 other user types. User just holds the common attributes for Companies and Customers. So basically user.rolable.id is in fact the id of a Company or a Customer, depending on which of them is logged in.

Comment: Well, in that case you can call user.rolable_id directly, which is less expensive.

Comment: True, good point. Anyway, I still have not found a solution. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you made sure that the request you are trying to show or destroy actually has dialogs and if so, that these dialogs have a company_id?

Comment: Also what exactly goes wrong? Can nobody see the request, or can everybody see it?

Comment: Everybody can see them. Each Request has many Dialogs, each of the dialogs belonging to one company. I think I might need to use a combination of both request_id and company_id in order to restrict access to only one request. I know it sounds a bit complicated, but it's actually fairly simple.

Comment: I've tried using both the request_id and the company_id, but it's not working.

Comment: Alright, could you post some more code? I'm particularly interested in your controller. Even better would be if you could create a small git repository on github that shows your problem.

Comment: Sure, @Arjan, thank you a lot for your help. I will do it sometime today, but a bit later as I have to go right now. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

You can always define abilities using blocks:

```
can [:show, :destroy], Request do |request|    
  request.dialogs.where(company_id: user.rolable.id).any?
end
```

Not sure if I nailed the condition you where looking for, but you get the picture.